# Multiply string - [Leetcode] Problem with Java

Tags: java, logic

**Question is:**

Given two non-negative integers num1 and num2 represented as strings, return the product of num1 and num2, also represented as a string.

Note: You must not use any built-in BigInteger library or convert the inputs to integer directly.

**Code:**

```
class Solution {
    public String multiply(String num1, String num2) {
        long n1=0, n2=0, res;
        n1 =  Long.parseLong(num1);
        n2 =  Long.parseLong(num2);
        res = n1 * n2;
        String str = Long.toString(res);
        return str;
    }
}
```

**Question is:**

Its working properly when I give smaller number is like:

> Input :40,
> 90

> Output:3600

> Input :100,
> 2099

> Output:209900

If i give input like this:

> Input :498828660196, 840477629533

> Output:"-3269442614257959980"

But the Actual output is : 419254329864656431168468. I don't know why answer coming like this. am also using long datatype. Anyone explain me and give solution for this problem.

Comment: it is called overflow, more here https://www.baeldung.com/java-overflow-underflow

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thank you guys!

I find the Solution.

```
class Solution {
    public String multiply(String num1, String num2) {
         if (num1.equals("0") || num2.equals("0")) return "0";
        int l1 = num1.length(), l2 = num2.length(), l = l1 + l2;
        char[] ans = new char[l];
        char[] c1 = num1.toCharArray();
        char[] c2 = num2.toCharArray();
        for (int i = l1 - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
            int c = c1[i] - '0';
            for (int j = l2 - 1; j >= 0; --j) {
                ans[i + j + 1] +=  c * (c2[j] - '0');
            }
        }
        for (int i = l - 1; i > 0; --i) {
            if (ans[i] > 9) {
                ans[i - 1] += ans[i] / 10;
                ans[i] %= 10;
            }
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int i = 0;
        for (; ; ++i) if (ans[i] != 0) break;
        for (; i < ans.length; ++i) sb.append((char) (ans[i] + '0'));
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem says "You must not use any built-in BigInteger library" and you start by importing BigInteger!

Answer (score 0):

Because you are storing it in Long and the range of long is up to 10^18 sort of but the answer which will come is of 10^23 range so it is throwing some garbage value as it is out of its range of storing, that is why you have return type of string as you can store it in string not in a long datatype.

Comment: oh alright, How to fix this problem because they asking convert the string to integer and then multiply the both string value to return the answer as string

Comment: @DeepakAnanth you may easily find various ways of solving the problem in its discussion page. Leetcode's discussion page is the best resource you can get for this.

Answer (score 0):

A Long is stored on 64 bits, with a maximum capacity of 2^63 - 1 (9.223372e+18)
so you are out of range. I suggest that you are pushing your test too far.
You could have changed to BigInteger if it were not proscribed, or to float, but for the purpose of your question assume that it's ok that these numbers are out range.
If you want you could check that the inputs are below 10^9 and throw an out of range error.

Comment: Rule is must not use any built-in BigInteger library